# Unity: ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenShot() is rotating the image upsidedown on VR and I have no idea why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Like the title suggests I am attempting to screenshot what the player is looking at but the photo is almost upside down and I have absolutely no idea what is going on. I have tried going through other forum posts but I can't find anyone having the same issue as me

Comment: Which Unity version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set both eyes and use StereoScreenCaptureMode

```
void TakeScreenShot()
{
    ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot("YourFileName", StereoScreenCaptureMode.BothEyes);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply! However the image is still flipped? I am not sure what I am doing wrong at this point -_-